# Rails docx gem zip error

Tags: ruby, docx

I am trying to use [docx gem](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx) to use .docx file in my seed and [docx-html gem](https://github.com/mportiz08/docx-html)  to convert its content to html to display on page easilly. But I am having some troubles creating a Docx::Document object for my docx file.
**seeds.rb**

---

```
...
    d = Docx::Document.open('app/assets/seed/seed2.docx')
    d.to_html
...
```

---

And thats the error I get evry time i try to run `rake db:seed`

```
Zip::ZipError: Zip end of central directory signature not found
```

Do any of You have solution to this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/chrahunt/docx/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

The `Zip::ZipError: Zip end of central directory signature not found` indicates that the zip is probably corrupt.

docx files are zipped files.

You can determine if the zip is corrupted or not by trying to unzip it from your favorite zip program.